# Get HOUR from AT TIME ZONE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetimeoffset

My DB is in Azure. I need my local (Israel) time.

```
SELECT GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Israel Standard Time', 
        DATEPART(HOUR,(GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Israel Standard Time'))
```

returns 13:

```
(No column name)                (No column name)
2018-12-07 13:43:34.893 +02:00  13
```

I need it to return 15, since it's 13 (+2)=15
I want to do it without adding 2 hard-coded.

Comment: `GETDATE()` already is local time (for some value of "local") and has no time zone info -- adding some with `AT TIME ZONE` won't produce correct results unless by making assumptions. Are your sure you don't want something like `SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Israel Standard Time')` instead? Note that the "hour" may not be enough information if the date changes as a result of the offset.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Israel Standard Time'
      ,DATEPART(HOUR,(GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Israel Standard Time'))
      ,DATEPART(HOUR,(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, GETDATE(), 121) AT TIME ZONE 'Israel Standard Time'))
```